# Prove that the row-space and column-space of A have that same dimension via the below specific steps

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let A be an mxn matrix with entries from a field.

Our objective is to prove that the row-space and column-space of A have that same dimension i.e. the same rank.

a) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2254859/231663

b) As a follow on from part (a) Suppose that A is in reduced echelon form. Use part (a) to show that its row-space and column-space have the same dimension.

c) Show that if A′ is obtained from A by an elementary row operation, then the row-space of A′ is equal to the row-space of A.

d) Give an example showing that if A′ is obtained from A by an elementary row operation, then the column- space of A′ is not necessarily equal to the column-space of A.

e) Suppose that A′ is obtained from A by an elementary row operation. Show that a collection of columns of A is linearly independent if and only if the corresponding collection of columns in A′ is linearly independent. More precisely show that if c1, . . . , cn are the columns of A, c′1, . . . , c′n are the columns of A′ and J ⊆ {1,...,n}, then {ci : i ∈ J} is linearly independent if and only if {c′i : i ∈ J} is linearly independent.

f) Conclude that the row-space and column-space of A have the same dimension.

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: This Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) might help.

Comment: Just to clarify I don't believe this is a duplicate. It might attempt to reach the same answer but the exercise gives precise instructions of how to get there. Hence it is not the same.